# VLC cannot see data drive

Tags: mount, hard-drive, vlc

VLC returns

```
filesystem error: cannot open file
/mnt/f9645e38-8086-48a1-9fcb-55548ea1ff3b/Videos II/3913103.mp4 
(No such file or directory)
```

when trying to access files from my data drive since the 18.04 upgrade. That is when opening the file directly.

Previously the drives were located in `media/user/drive/folder/file`. Even when trying to open from vlc the browser doesn’t even see the drive by name or that designation. As for the drive access I had to point Clementine and Calibre but both now work.

The other differences are I recently added dvd support (I cant remember if I tried to run off that drive before I did) and the drive is set to automount.

Answer (score 2):

After bootup and the latest update installed I went into Synaptic to reinstall VLC and found it and most of it's libs not installed, it was 3.0.3.1. Checked my version, it was 3.0.4. Installed the older version and everything works from the data drive. Still have to grab a dvd and check that.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert, but I did encounter a similar problem with VLC not being able to see files outside of the home directory.
On searching the forums, I discovered that there are two different versions of VLC. The Snap version is different to that when you install via command line.
The Snap version is unable to view files outside of the parent directory (apparently). The command-line version can.
If you are having trouble accessing files on external or secondary drives, check which version you have installed.
Recommended action - remove snap version of VLC. Install VLC via the command-line.